# Can I get the path of the painted text in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, paint, ondraw

I have a custom TextView subclass and want to access/calculate the Path that is used to paint the text. I don't want to paint the text myself in onDraw but let TextView display it. Is there any way to get that path as a Path object?

Comment: no Path is used,  it is done by android.text.Layout class

Comment: Dammit, thank you for that information

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val textPath = Path()
val paint: TextPaint = getPaint()
paint.getTextPath(text, 0, text.length(), 0, y_cor, textPath)
```

The textPath is the result you wanted.